# Find Length of Longest String in a Collection in Clojure

Tags: clojure

This seems like it should be comically easy but I somehow can't figure it out: how do you find the length of the longest string in a collection in Clojure?

e.g.  `(fn ["cat", "dog", "bear"]) => 4`

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried?

Comment: Sure! I tried (max (count coll)), which intuitively "seemed" right to me but which just gives the number of items in the collection. Then I read up on "apply" and "reduce", and tried various combinations like (apply max count coll) but those all threw errors. I know this is a cliche but I don't really understand how to think about this problem in Clojure -- in Python (etc) I know three different ways to do it, but I think conceptually I don't understand how Clojure works yet.

Comment: p.s. is it generally considered good etiquette to list several things I've tried in the question itself, or as a comment, or something else? I'm assuming that other beginners will land on this page in future when trying to do the same thing so I was trying to keep the question as succinct as possible, but can be more expansive in future if that's preferred!

Comment: Yes you can put them in the question itself.

Comment: @marbiru [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helps explain what makes a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(max (count coll))` is counting the collection, which returns 3, and then taking the `max` of 3 (and nothing) results in 3. This is not what you want.

`(apply max count coll)` results in `(max count "cat" "dog" "bear")` which leads to comparing a symbol and strings with `max`, and that throws an exception because `max` expects one or more numbers.

`(fn ["cat", "dog", "bear"])` is not valid syntax and results in an exception that `fn` does not conform to the spec. The special form `fn` takes as first argument a vector of symbols (binding-form) (or optionally the name and than third argument the binding-form) . E.g., `(fn ident [n] n))` is a function with the name ident that takes an argument `n` and returns `n`, `((fn [n] n) 1) ;; => 1`.

So taking these things in mind, one approach is to first determine the counts of the elements in the `coll` and then finding the `max` of that coll.

`(def coll ["cat" "dog" "bear"])` (or use a set `#{"cat" "dog" "bear"}` if you don't need duplicates)

Here are a few ways to do so:

`(apply max (map count coll)) ;; => 4`
turn the collection in collection of counts `[3 3 4]` and `apply max` to get `(max 3 3 4)`.

`(reduce max (map count coll)) ;; => 4` Same as above but reduce the collection by taking `max` of first element only, then second element with `max` of previous result, and so on.

And depending on what you need you can do things like:

`(group-by count coll) ;; => {3 ["cat" "dog"], 4 ["bear"]}`

`(sort-by count ["a" "aa" "aaa" "aa" "aaaaa" "a"]) ;; => ("a" "a" "aa" "aa" "aaa" "aaaaa")`

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer. One more question: when I wrote " (fn ["cat", "dog", "bear"]) " I didn't realise "fn" was specific syntax, I was just trying to say "some function or operator which, when performed on ["cat", "dog", "bear"], returns 4" -- what would the idiomatically Clojure-y way to express that be?

Comment: @marbiru Just `f` is a pretty common placeholder for a generic function. `g` is usually used after for a second function. In most cases though, it's best to use a specific name unless the function truly is generic (like what would be given to `map`). For you example, I probably would have written `(longest-string ["cat", "dog", "bear"]) => 4`, or something similar. Explicit it good.

Answer (score 2):

```clj
user=> ((fn [strs] (apply max (map count strs))) ["cat" "dog" "bear"])
4
```

Comment: A code-only answer is okay, but explanation will help others. You're giving a fish, but not teaching how to fish. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22357163).